# Token isn´t seting in cookies even though it is on postman

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies

In my user controller y have a signup function that when the user is added creates a token and sets it in a cookie 'jwt'. (i will leave ir below this text ) but even though i see it set in postman i can see it in the browser.

```
const signToken = (id) => {
  return jwt.sign({ id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN,
  })
}

const createSendToken = (user, statusCode, req, res) => {
  const token = signToken(user._id)

  res.cookie('jwt', token, {
    expires: new Date(
      Date.now() + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES_IN * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    ),
    HttpOnly: true,
    secure: true,
    withCredentials: true,
    // secure: req.secure || req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] === 'https',
  })

  user.password = undefined

  res.status(statusCode).json({
    messsage: 'success',
    token,
    data: {
      user,
    },
  })
}

exports.signup = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const newUser = await User.create({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    passwordConfirm: req.body.passwordConfirm,




  })

  const url = `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/me`
  await new Email(newUser, url).sendWelcome()
  createSendToken(newUser, 201, req, res)
})
```

So i´ve read that because im managing my app from 2 different ports this can set an issue, and the cookies can only be set if the request is being sent form the same host. (please correct me if im wrong). Giving this i tried to use the http-proxy-middleware but also failed.
My backend is at http://localhost:5000 and my frontend at http://localhost:5173
This code is my app.js file.

```
const express = require('express')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const rateLimit = require('express-rate-limit')
const helmet = require('helmet')
const cors = require('cors')
const mongoSanitize = require('express-mongo-sanitize')
const xss = require('xss-clean')
const hpp = require('hpp')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const AppError = require('./utils/appError')
const globalErrorHandler = require('./controllers/errorController')
const productRouter = require('./routes/productRoutes')
const userRouter = require('./routes/userRoutes')
const categoryRouter = require('./routes/categoryRoutes')
const reviewRouter = require('./routes/reviewRoutes')

const app = express()

// Set security HTTP headers
app.use(helmet())
// app.use(morgan('dev'))
// Development logging
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  app.use(morgan('dev'))
}

const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:5173',
  credentials: true,
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions))

app.use(cookieParser())

// Limit requests from same API
const limiter = rateLimit({
  max: 100,
  windowMs: 60 * 60 * 1000,
  message: 'Too many requests from this IP, please try again in an hour!',
})

app.use('/api', limiter)

// Body parser, reading data from body into req.body
app.use(express.json({ limit: '10kb' })) // Body limit is 10 kb

// Data sanitization against NoSQL query injection
app.use(mongoSanitize())
// Data sanitization against XSS
app.use(xss())
// Prevent parameter pollution
app.use(
  hpp({
    whitelist: ['condition', 'price', 'sort', 'limit', 'page', 'fields'],
  })
)

// Serving static files
app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/public`))

// ROUTES
app.use('/api/v1/products', productRouter)
app.use('/api/v1/users', userRouter)
app.use('/api/v1/categories', categoryRouter)
app.use('/api/v1/reviews', reviewRouter)

app.all('*', (req, res, next) => {
  next(new AppError(`Can't find ${req.originalUrl} on this server!`, 404))
})

app.use(globalErrorHandler)

module.exports = app
```

And this is my server.js file you can see commented how i tried to use the http-proxy-middlewar

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const app = require('./app')
// const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware')

process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
  console.log('UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION!  Shutting down...')
  console.log(err)
  process.exit(1)
})

dotenv.config({ path: './config.env' })

const DB = process.env.DATABASE.replace('<PASSWORD>', process.env.PASSWORD)

mongoose
  .connect(DB, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
  })
  .then(() => console.log('DB connection successful!'))

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000

// app.use('/api', (req, res, next) => {
//   console.log('Middleware de proxy ejecutado para la ruta:', req.url)
//   proxyMiddleware(req, res, next)
// })

// const proxyMiddleware = createProxyMiddleware({
//   target: 'http://localhost:5000', // La dirección de tu servidor backend
//   changeOrigin: true, // Cambiar el encabezado de origen a la dirección del servidor proxy
//   pathRewrite: {
//     '^/api': '', // Puedes establecer una ruta base si es necesario (por ejemplo, '/api')
//   },
// })

// Aplica el middleware de proxy para todas las solicitudes que coincidan con /api
// app.use('/api', proxyMiddleware)

// const PORT = 5173

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`)
})

process.on('unhandledRejection', (err) => {
  console.log(err)
  console.log('UNHANDLED REJECTION!  Shutting down...')
  server.close(() => {
    process.exit(1)
  })
})
```

Thanks in advance!